# How do I use the curve modifier to make an object connects from one end to the other accurately?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

So I am trying to curve this somewhat 3D flat plained object into an accurately divided cylindrical object.

[image]

But whenever I tried to scale the BezierCircle up with an increment, it would always be off by a tiny bit

[image]

Can someone help guide me with this?